# dlopen() returns null when dynamic library is codesigned using distribution certification on iOS

Tags: ios, dlopen, dynamic-library

Hi I am working on iOS app using dynamic library.

Here is the problem I am encounting recently.
I apply dynamic library which consists of nativce fuctions.

It is ok when I use dlopen() to load dynamic library with codesigning developer certificaton.
However, dlopen() returns null which means 'loading library failed' using dynamic library with codesigning distribution certification to verify the app is ok on release mode.

Is there any problem during testing process? 
Please advise me on right direction.